# Adding scrollview to Edditext

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I have an input box - edittext in android, which is not single line. I want that when three lines are complete then the edittext should stop expanding and scrollview should attach to the edittext at that time.

I can add scrollview directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `android:maxLines="3"` for your `EditText` tag in xml.

Comment: How to scroll then after three lines??

Comment: try android:isScrollContainer

Answer (score 3):

try like this way

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/users_first_name" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:hint="First"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:maxLines="3"
   >
    </EditText>
```